# Hyperparameter tuning with multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the function for tuning hyperparameters for the model

```
def modelHPTuning(X_train, y_train, hyperparams):
    classifier = ExtraTreesClassifier()
    grid = GSCV(classifier, hyperparams)
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
    best_hyperparameters = grid_result.best_params_
    return best_hyperparameters

best_hyperparameters = modelHPTuning(X_train, y_train, XRT_Hyperparams)
```

For multiprocessing, I tried

```
pool = Pool(4)
best_hyperparameters = pool.starmap(modelHPTuning, X_train, y_train, XRT_Hyperparams)
pool.close()
```

getting error

```
TypeError: starmap() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I tried

```
zip(X_train, y_train, XRT_Hyperparams)
```

getting

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How to fix the arguments, GSCV function is just creating a grid space for GridSearchCV

Comment: It would be helpful (mostly to you, ultimately) if we knew what types `X_train`, `y_train` and `XRT_Hyperparams` were,  what type of parameters `modelHPTuning` was expecting and *where* you were getting the exception.

Comment: X_train, y_train are ndarray of shape (1050.18) and (1050.), XRT_Hyperparams is a dictionary of parameters {'n_estimators': [100,200,300,400],'max_depth': [2,3,4,5]}, starmap exception is from args of pool.starmap

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really answer what type of parameters `modelHPTuning` was expecting. Its arguments *X_train*, *y_train*, *hyperparams* cannot be the same type as the actual values being used in `starmap` :`X_train`, `y_train`, `XRT_Hyperparams`.

The arguments to `starmap` is a function and a *single iterable*. If that function takes, for example, two arguments (we'll call them *x* and *y*), then that single iterable will typically be a `list` or `tuple` containing one or more lists or tuples *each contains two elements* for the two arguments  that the function takes. For example:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def f(x, y):
    print(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [9, 10]
    y = [90, 100]
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(f, [[9, 90], [90, 100]])
```

Prints:

```
9 90
90 100
```

**In other words, you must be passing to `starmap` a function and multiples of the type(s) of value(s) that the function is expecting.**

If you have the `x` and `y` values to be passed to function `f` in individual iterables, then you would use builtin function `zip` to create the single iterable required by `starmap`:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def f(x, y):
    print(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [9, 10]
    y = [90, 100]
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(f, zip(x, y))
```

Prints:

```
9 90
90 100
```

If your function `f` has one or more arguments for which you need to always pass the same value (in the following example argument *caption*), the easiest way to do that is to use function `functools.partial`:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from functools import partial

def f(x, y, caption):
    print(caption, x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [9, 10]
    y = [90, 100]
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(partial(f, caption='The values are:'), zip(x, y))
```

Prints:

```
The values are: 9 90
The values are: 90 100
```

The other way to accomplish this if you are using `zip` to build your parameter list for `starmap` is to use `itertools.repeat`, but this can be far more costly:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from itertools import repeat

def f(x, y, caption):
    print(caption, x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [9, 10]
    y = [90, 100]
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(f, zip(x, y, repeat('The values are:')))
```

Prints:

```
The values are: 9 90
The values are: 90 100
```

**With the above examples, you should now be able to figure out what you need to be using as values for `starmap` and arguments to `modelHPTuning`.**